# What if OOM happens for the complete output mode in spark structured streaming

Tags: apache-spark

I am new and learning spark structured streaming,

I have following code that is using `complete` as the output mode

```
import java.util.Date

import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.Trigger
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType

object StreamingWordCount {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder
      .appName("StreamingWordCount")
      .config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", 1)
      .master("local[2]")
      .getOrCreate()

    import spark.implicits._

    val lines = spark
      .readStream
      .schema(new StructType().add("value", "string"))
      .option("maxFilesPerTrigger", 1)
      .text("file:///" + data_path)
      .as[String]

    val wordCounts = lines.flatMap(_.split(" ")).groupBy("value").count()

    val query = wordCounts.writeStream
      .queryName("t")
      .outputMode("complete")
      .format("memory")
      .start()


    while (true) {

      spark.sql("select * from t").show(truncate = false)
      println(new Date())
      Thread.sleep(1000)
    }


    query.awaitTermination()
  }
}
```

A quick question is that over time, the spark runtime remembers  too many states of word and count, so OOM should happen at some time,

I would ask how to do in practice for such kind of scenario.

Answer (score 1):

**Memory sink** should be used only for debugging purposes on low data volumes as the entire output will be collected and stored in the driver’s memory. The output will be stored in memory as an in-memory table.

So if OOM error occurs, the driver will crashes and all the state maintained in Driver's memory will be lost.

The same applies for **Console sink** as well.

Comment: Thanks @lakshman-battini. With the `Complete` output mode,  Even for `Console sink` or others, like Kakfa sink, the driver still can crash over time since there will be so many states that the spark has to keep tracking, so I am asking with the `Complete` mode, how to avoid OOM.

Comment: When would complete be used in reality?